# Angularjs show events if the end date is not passed

Tags: angularjs

I have a 2 pages one for Past Events and one for Upcoming events. I want to put a condition so that I Can check if the event end date is not over then show it on Upcoming events page if the end date is over then show it on Past Events page. I want to know how can I do that.

I checked the filter option but I was not able to do it with that. I also tried ng-if but hides the complete section.

I am sharing some sample code here below.

```
<h1>**Upcoming Events**</h1>
<div ng-repeat="_event in events">
  <div class="event-details pull-left">
    <p>{{_event.title}}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="event-date pull-left">
    <p> {{_event.startDate}} - {{_event.endDate}} </p>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>**Past Events**</h1>
<div ng-repeat="_event in events">
  <div class="event-details pull-left">
    <p>{{_event.title}}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="event-date pull-left">
    <p> {{_event.startDate}} - {{_event.endDate}} </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you provide some sample data of events, It would be easy to work with

Comment: event title : 3rd international conference. start date: 25 August 2017. End Date: 28 August 2017. Location : City State University Hong Kong. 

event title : 2rd international conference. start date: 25 August 2016. End Date: 28 August 2016. Location : City State University Hong Kong.

Comment: Try it like `<div ng-repeat="_event in events" ng-if="_event.endDate>Date.now()">...`, assuming `endDate` is a date property.

Comment: this completely hides one section

Comment: For upcoming ith should be `_event.endDate>Date.now()` and for past events it has to be `_event.endDate<Date.now()`

Comment: but how can I use it in my current code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function in your controller

```
$scope.greaterThan = function(){
  var prop='endDate';
  var val=Date.now();
  return function(item){
    return new Date(item[prop]) < val;
  }
};
```

and in your html

```
ng-repeat="_event in events| filter:greaterThan()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Example with ng-if: I use a function for the date filter part in the controller.

HTML part:

```
<body ng-controller="AppController as app" class="container-fluid">

  <h2>**Upcoming Events**</h2>
  <div ng-repeat="_event in app.events" ng-if="app.checkUpcomingEvent(_event.endDate)">
    <div class="event-details pull-left">
      <p>{{_event.title}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="event-date pull-left">
      <p> {{_event.startDate | date:'longDate'}} - {{_event.endDate | date:'longDate'}} </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h2>**Past Events**</h2>
  <div ng-repeat="_event in app.events" ng-if="app.checkPastEvent(_event.endDate)">
    <div class="event-details pull-left">
      <p>{{_event.title}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="event-date pull-left">
      <p> {{_event.startDate | date:'longDate'}} - {{_event.endDate | date:'longDate'}} </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Angular part:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
.controller('AppController', function() {
      this.events = [
          {title: 'Event A', startDate: new Date('2017/08/1'), endDate: new Date('2017/08/2')},
         {title: 'Event B', startDate: new Date('2017/08/2'), endDate: new Date('2017/08/3')},
         {title: 'Event C', startDate: new Date('2017/08/3'), endDate: new Date('2017/08/4')},
         {title: 'Event D', startDate: new Date('2042/08/1'), endDate: new Date('2042/08/2')},
         {title: 'Event E', startDate: new Date('2042/08/2'), endDate: new Date('2042/08/3')},
         {title: 'Event F', startDate: new Date('2042/08/3'), endDate: new Date('2042/08/4')},
      ];

      this.checkPastEvent= function(endDate) { 
          return endDate < Date.now() ;
      }

      this.checkUpcomingEvent= function(endDate) { 
          return endDate > Date.now();
      }


});
angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
```

running example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/upq4t2hz/